# Deserialize a complex JSON object having DynamicJsonArray to dynamic

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I have a client that sends `SomeComplexObject` to a webservice.

I want the webservice to be unaware of the structure of the data,
so want the data to be deserialized to a dynamic that is passed then to a method that knows how to deal with it.

I use `System.Web.Helpers.Json.Encode()`, `Decode()` methods 
and I have a problem when SomeComplexObject contains a collection.
It is deserialized to a DynamicJsonArray but it is somehow not accessible
for the consumer of the data.

These are Model types.

```
public class Aaa
{
    public Bbb B { get; set; }
    public List<Ccc> Cccs { get; set; }
}

public class Bbb
{
    public long Key { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
}

public class Ccc
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Let us say that I have a `myAaa` object of type `Aaa` with a property of type `Bbb`
and a list of 42 `Ccc` objects.

Now:

```
var MyAaaSerialized = System.Web.Helpers.Json.Encode(MyAaa);
```

Then I send it and then:

```
var MyAaaDeserialized = System.Web.Helpers.Json.Decode(MyAaaSerialized);
```

And finally: 
This is the code of the consumer. `Email` and `emailService` are `Postal` classes.

```
dynamic email = new Email(template);
email.Data = MyAaaDeserialized;
email.User = user;
this.emailService.Send(email);
```

I can see in the sent email that properties of B object are accessible.
However, properties of members of Cccs list are not.

Of course with `email.Data = MyAaa;`    everything works OK.

Is there any dead simple way to serialize/deserialize a complex object that contains a collection?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: If you posted a sample JSON and the Data property we would have more to play with.

Comment: You are right. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I was wrong. `System.Web.Helpers.Json.Encode()` and `Decode()` work correctly. I`ll tell you what happened:

I used to use Postal mailsender locally, i.e. I used to take my super-complex POCO object and pass it as a dynamic to Postal Email class. And it worked.

Now I want some webservice to send emails so I need to pass serialized data to it. I have sent a test email and I`ve seen that values of some of the fields are not present in the email message, but 'DynamicJsonObject' is there instead. So I assumed (wrong), that the structure of deserialized object is somehow corrupted.

But the truth is different:

The missing data is of complex type, say

```
public class Money 
{
    public double Amount {get; set;}
    public string Currency {get; set;}

    public override ToString()
    {...}
}
```

So when I asked in Razor email template for:

`@item.Prices.SalePriceGross` locally,

it somehow must have used the `ToString()` method.
And of course in a serialized / deserialized object there is no knowledge about the `ToString()` method.

I am going to need to expose a property with the string I want to display or (better) access `Amount` and `Currency` explicitly and process them in Razor email template.

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

If I haven't misunderstood your question, it can be resolved by using the Decode overload that uses generics as below. Just specifying the type (Aaa in this case) worked for me in the code below and it printed all ccc properties correctly:

```
var myAaa = new Aaa()
{
    B = new Bbb() { Name = "someone", DateOfBirth = DateTime.Today.AddYears(-20) },
    Cccs = Enumerable.Repeat<Ccc>(new Ccc() { Age = 20, Name = "someone else" }, 42).ToList()
};

var MyAaaSerialized = System.Web.Helpers.Json.Encode(myAaa);
var MyAaaDeserialized = System.Web.Helpers.Json.Decode<Aaa>(MyAaaSerialized);
dynamic data = MyAaaDeserialized; 
foreach (Ccc newCccs in data.Cccs)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{newCccs.Name}\t{newCccs.Age}");
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but as I wrote: "I want the webservice to be unaware of the structure of the data, so want the data to be deserialized to a dynamic that is passed then to a method that knows how to deal with it." I want any dynamic content to be sent to the Postal service that knows (by having a proper Razor template) how to deal with it. I webservice should not know about Aaa type and all other types that I probably want to use.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that bit. Could you please post the Email class as well. I'll update my answer or delete it if it doesn't work

Comment: I think in your example the Email service doesn't still know anything about Aaa. The consumer knows about it and assigns it to a dynamic object. That's why I requested the Email class, to be sure what's inside that class